# Не подключается jquery при работе с bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Подключаю такие вот библиотеки:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="app"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

При попытке воспользоваться каким-либо свойством `bootstrap`, возникает ошибка `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`. Код целиком можно посмотреть [здесь](https://plnkr.co/edit/sRc9VQZOEd541WKiWN8B?p=info).

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Переставьте строчки местами - сначала подключите jquery, а потом bootstrap.

Comment: @cronfy пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы подключаете jquery после bootstrap.min.js, соответственно, когда выполняются скрипты из бутстрапа jquery еще нет. Вот так:

```
<script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="app"></script>
```

Еще смущает очень старая версия jquery, попробуйте подключать что-нибудь новое (сейчас актуальна 3.1.1). Вероятно бутстрапу нужна более новая, чем у вас.

Comment: У меня проблема. Не раскрывается выпадающий список Bootstrap. Нашел проблему в неправильно подключенном JQuery. Взял 3 ссылки с оф.сайта. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ Но это мне не решает проблему. Приведенные выше строки на подключения решили проблему, но они старые. Где найти более новые?